# Remove entire row if there are no values in the cells

Tags: reportingservices-2005

[image]

I need to remove the entire row if there is no X (Issued). The data retrieved, returns Rated and Issued items but I only want to display Issued.

The logic at the bottom stipulates that only form name: GL and status: Issued (green) should display and I don't understand why Rated items (red) are taking up space.

I've tried to make them hidden at the column level but naturally there are big gaping holes with no lines representing the rows but there is still empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but why are you hiding at the column level? You should be able to hide a row using an expression like this:

```
=Iif(Fields!Status.Value <> "Issued", True, False)
```

Another option is to apply a filter to the data region using similar logic.

Comment: I resolved the issue with applying a filter by data region. Thanks for the advice!!!